# How can I get the type and version of file system I use in VxWorks

Tags: vxworks

I need to know which type of file system every partition on my VxWorks system is formatted with. I need a type of file system and a version, of it (if possible).

May be there is some kind of command, function to get that info ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there isn't a command that will give you these details. However, `iosDevShow` and `iosFdShow` will give you information about the open devices and file descriptors.

Comment: Actually, I was asking about the type of file system, like DOSFS or HRFS. Can I deduce this information using functions you suggested? I am not sure how. Regards.